# Do you agree, or do you have to think about it?

Tags: knowledge, pattern

Try make sense of the characters written below. It should lead you to a person.

C: **57 350 676** (6)  E: **68 79** (4) GL **18** I Ma (3)

Who is this person?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concealed person is:

> the French philosopher, mathematician and scientist, [**René Descartes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes)

Why? The list of characters can be split into 3 sections representing 3 words that must be found. Each section ends with an enumeration in brackets showing the length of the word to be found...

**C: 57 350 676 (6)**

> Here, 'C' stands for '**Country**'. If we interpret the three numbers that follow as [country calling codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) then these correspond to:
>
>  57=Colombia, 350=Gibraltar, 676=Tonga
>
>  Using their [2-letter ISO codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) (which coincidentally here are also just their first two letters), we get the required 6-letter answer **CO+GI+TO**.

**E: 68 79 (4)**

> Here, 'E' stands for '**Element**'. Looking up the elements of the [Periodic Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) with these atomic numbers, we get Erbium and Gold. Taking the first two letters of each we get the 4-letter answer **ER+GO**.

**GL: 18 I Ma (3)**

> Here, 'GL' stands for '**Greek letter**'. The 18th letter of the [Greek alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet) is Sigma. 'I Ma' represents the first halves of the words '*In Math*'. We are being asked to find what the letter Sigma represents in mathematics, and the 3-letter answer is **[SUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)**.

Overall, then we have:

> **[Cogito, ergo sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum)** - the famous Latin philosophical statement made by Descartes which usually translates into English as '*I think, therefore I am*'.

And as for the title - do I agree, or do I have to think about it...?

> I agree. (At least I *think* so...!)

Comment: .. Well done :)